# Properties of a dense subalgebra of $C_0(G)$ when restricted to a closed subset of $G.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let G be a locally compact space.

If $A$ is a dense subalgebra of $C_0(G)$ (continuous functions vanishing at infinity), for a closed subset $S\subset G$, does it follow that $\{f\in A: \hspace{0.07cm}f|_S \equiv 0\}$ is dense in $\{f\in C_0(G): \hspace{0.07cm} f|_S\equiv 0\}$, provided that the former set is non-empty. Is it true in general that $A|_S$ is dense in $C_0(G)|_S$ with the relative topology on $S$?

I am a bit confused with how to approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between $f|_S =$ or $\equiv 0$?

Comment: Do you not mean $C_0[G]$ in the two spots where you wrote $C[G]$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma My apologies for the sloppy notation - it has been corrected.

Comment: Which topology is considered on $C_0(G)$? Can you add a definition of a function vanishing at infinity?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is no. Let $G= (0,1).$ Note each $f\in C_0((0,1))$ extends to a unique continuous function on $[0,1]$ that vanishes at the end points. Now any such continuous function is the uniform limit on $[0,1]$ of polynomials that vanish at the end points. (This follows from Weierstrass with a little fine-tuning.) Let $A$ be the algebra of such polynomials. Then $A$ is dense in $C_0((0,1)).$

Suppose $S=[1/2,1).$ Then $S$ is closed in $G.$ Note that any polynomial vanishing on $S$ must equal $0$ everywhere. Thus $A|_S$ is $\{0\},$ and so we fail to have the desired density of $A|_S$ by a mile.

The answer to your second question seems to be yes, and it is very easy to show. I'll let you think about that for a bit.